# Decode URL with ampersand

Tags: php

The following URL gets cut off after the ampersand.

```
http://localhost:8888/teams/ncaa/Alabama%20A%26M%20Bulldogs
```

The last parameter ($_GET['team']) gets cut off so that when I echo it out, it's simply

```
Alabama A
```

That parameter is encoded as follows

```
echo "<a href='/teams/ncaa/".urlencode($team[$i])."'>".$team[$i]."</a>";
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying that that URL appears in your output HTML but doesn't work, or that your code doesn't produce the correct URL?

Comment: What are you using to rewrite the URLs?

Comment: modrewrite. I have some rewrite statements in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Your RewriteRule certainly decodes and then appends the ampersand literally. You will need to peek at the `QUERY_STRING` or `REQUEST_URI` hence, not the GET param.

Comment: Good lord, Texas A&M, I've had issues with you in the past. That damn ampersand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
echo "<a href='/teams/ncaa/".urlencode($team[$i])."'>".$team[$i]."</a>";
```

To:

```
echo "<a href='/teams/ncaa/".rawurlencode($team[$i])."'>".$team[$i]."</a>";
```